# C++; Pass a std::array Random Access Iterator as a Function Parameter

Tags: c++, iterator, parameter-passing, quicksort, stdarray

So I've seen questions on here about how to pass through a `std::vector::iterator` as an argument parameter for a function, however, those solutions don't seem to apply when dealing with `std::array`s. What I want to use this for is a Quick Sort function that takes in `std::array`s. This is the code I have thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


// Function declarations.
template<size_t SIZE>
void QuickSort(array<int, SIZE> arrayName, array<int, SIZE>::iterator low, \
    array<int, SIZE>::iterator high);

template<size_t SIZE>
auto Partition(array<int, SIZE> arrayName, array<int, SIZE>::iterator low, \
    array<int, SIZE>::iterator high);

// Main function.
int main()
{
    // Set rand() seed to current time (NULL).
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    // Declare array "randomNumberArray" of size #.
    static array<int, 5> randomNumerArray = { 0 };

    // Initialize array with random numbers.
    for (auto it = randomNumerArray.begin(); it != randomNumerArray.end(); ++it)
        *it = rand() % 500 + 1;

    /*
    This is where I would want to use the Quick Sort function to sort the array and
    then print it out to the console.
    */

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}


// Function definitions. Standard Quick Sort syntax.
template<size_t SIZE>
void QuickSort(array<int, SIZE> arrayName, array<int, SIZE>::iterator low, \
    array<int, SIZE>::iterator high)
{
    if (low < high) {
        // Function definition to be finished.
    }

    return;
}

/* Partition() returns auto to easily return the variable type I need
which is a Random Access Iterator.*/
template<size_t SIZE>
auto Partition(array<int, SIZE> arrayName, array<int, SIZE>::iterator low, \
    array<int, SIZE>::iterator high)
{
    auto pivot = high;
    auto i = (low - 1);

    for (auto j = low; j < pivot; ++j) {
        if (*j < *pivot) {
            int tempNum = 0;
            tempNum = *(++i);
            *i = *j;
            *j = tempNum;
        }
    }

    int tempNum = 0;
    tempNum = *(++i);
    *i = *pivot;
    *pivot = tempNum;

    return i;
}
```

As you can see, I've managed how to fit most of the pieces to this puzzle, I just don't know how to pass through `low` and `high`, which are meant to be of Random Access Iterator types, as argument parameters to the functions. Using `std::array<type, size>::iterator` doesn't work as it's not a type. I've also tried to add `#include <iterator>`, but to no avail.

**EDIT:** To clarify, it's not the value contained within the index that I'm trying to pass through, but the index itself which changes with each recursion.

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference, in C++, between passing parameters by value versus by reference? If you do, take a look at your function again and see if you can apply you knowledge, and see the obvious problem. If you don't, perhaps you want to study this, first?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Hey, it's not the contained within the index that I need but the index itself of 'low' and 'high' which changes with each recursion.

Comment: Passing by value versus by reference has nothing to do, whatsoever, with whether something "it's not contained within the index", or not. Actually, why is the array getting passed in at all, in the first place? It does not seem to be even being used in the function, so what is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I haven't finished coding the function definition for QuickSort(), as you can see in the comment I made within the function. But you can take a look at Quick Sort functions, in other pages such as this one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/ if you want to see why I need it to be that way. Someone else already answered my question though, but thank you anyway ! Much appreciated.

Comment: Just use `template <class Iter>  void Quicksort(Iter first, Iter last)`. Quick sort doesn’t need to know that the sequence it’s sorting is managed by an array. None of the (incomplete) code in the question uses `arrayName`.

Comment: Well, when the passed in `arrayName` gets used, for whatever reason, don't be surprised if that parameter moves in mysterious ways, because the decision whether to pass it by value or reference went the wrong way. Unfortunately, web sites like geeksforgeeks, which promise to turn anyone into a C++ uberhacker simply by solving their coding puzzles, are just clickbait. They do nothing to explain the core fundamental principles of the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, and only after sinking massive amounts of time on it, do people realize that.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Oh don't worry, I'm not using geeksforgeeks to learn C++, I was only using it as a reference to look at their pseudo-code so I can write my own Quick Sort function. I'm actually learning how to code in C++ using a book called "Sams Teach Yourself C++" which is really good, and by watching various YouTube videos, mainly from a channel by the name of "Cherno" and his C++ playlist. He seems very informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `typename` to hint to the compiler that `iterator` is a type

```
template<size_t SIZE>
void QuickSort(typename array<int, SIZE>::iterator low,
               typename array<int, SIZE>::iterator high);
```

But that won't work either since `SIZE` is in a nondeduced context. It would be better to just make an `iterator` as a template

```
template<typename RandomIt>
void QuickSort(RandomIt low, RandomIt high);
```

Comment: Thank you ! You are a genius ! haha. Second time answering my question too.

Answer (score 0):

To provide an alternative with C++20 Concepts:

```
void Quicksort(std::random_access_iterator auto low,
    std::random_access_iterator auto high);
```

This will provide restrictions versus a regular template:

1. Checks that an iterator is provided.
2. Iterator supports random access to the underlying container.

Additional iterator types can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator

OR Google "iterator concepts c++20" if link becomes invalid.

Bonus: This would allow you to accept std::array AND std::vector. Containers such as std::set and std::list would not because the underlying implementation is a linked list. Double check the containers you want to be acceptable and adjust the concept used appropriately.